# Does the concept of “breaking scene” exist?

Tags: phrase-requests

The idea of `breaking character` is a common concept in English.

Wikipedia explains breaking character as:

> In theatre (especially in the illusionistic Western tradition), breaking character occurs when an actor ceases to maintain the illusion that they are identical with the character they are portraying.

Does the idea of breaking scene exist?

That is to say: destroying the illusion of the entire scene of work - as opposed to just a character.

Is there a more apt term?

Comment: Are there a significant number of relevant Google hits for "broke scene"? For "he/she/they broke scene"?

Comment: We don't call it *breaking scene*. It's called [*breaking the fourth wall*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22breaking+the+fourth+wall%22) (the imaginary divide between the real-world audience and the fictional world being portrayed on stage).

Comment: Depending on the actual context, you could also say **going off script**, **improvising**, or **reinterpreting**.

Answer (score 2):

While "Breaking Scene" is not generally a much-used term, it does break-down into two other terms used quite commonly in film:

**Breaking the Fourth Wall**: This occurs whenever an actor or character acknowledges the fictional nature of the work in some way. By its very nature, Breaking the Fourth Wall is deliberate, although it may present itself as unintentional, often for comedic effect.

**Discontinuity**: This occurs whenever something in a series of events "breaks" with those events, and it may not be obvious. Some examples include:

- When an obviously unfinished project in one shot is finished in the next immediate shots, or when an object in one shot is not present in later shots despite no feasible way for it to disappear.
- When a Character knows something they have no actual way of knowing based on the time period, like an enlisted US Soldier at Midway knowing that the war would be ended by an Atomic Bomb.

This may be done unintentionally (and almost always is), but it may also be done to draw the audience's attention to a certain fact, often to create dramatic tension. For example, a film involving Time Travel may use Discontinuity to point out that a certain character is a time traveller, or that someone is "editing" the timeline of the film.

It is also important to note that any instance where equipment, like a Boom Mic, is visible has pretty-much the same effect as Discontinuity.